# I need Black background in portrait taken in daylight

Tags: post-processing, portrait

[image]

I want to get black background in portrait and effect like this,check my attach image file.
by using which software I can get this,I guess by Lightroom but I try and failed.So Please anyone help me to get out of this problem

Comment: I wouldn't use Lightroom, although it is probably possible. I would use Photoshop or GIMP if you don't have PS. Convert to BW, add some layer masks and start messing with the levels. You'll get it.

Comment: Or you could just shoot it correctly to *kill the ambient*.   http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/34392/15871

Comment: See also:   http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/18537/15871

Answer (score 5):

Lightroom isn't designed for this type of photo editing; this is what Photoshop is designed to do. Even if you don't eventually use Photoshop, search Google/Youtube for "Photoshop Masking", or "Replace Background Photoshop". There are literally hundreds of tutorials that will walk you through how to mask.

Answer (score 3):

Little late, but here's your answer:

I found the photographer, [Mohammad Zia Ali, on Facebook,](https://www.facebook.com/ziaali183/) and came across [this incredible video](https://www.facebook.com/ziaali183/videos/vb.377233715755271/523001497845158) he posted on his post-processing technique using Adobe Camera RAW and Photoshop. Make sure you watch in HD.

Comment: You might want to describe the actual steps in the video tutorial, since links tend to go stale over time.